# variations package

Tags: tables

I'm trying to set up a table of variations, something rather unique at French schools. To produce them in latex, a special package was written, which predefines everything needed to draw this tables and uses the tabular environment. It can be downloaded [here](http://obrecht.fr/variations/).  Unfortunately I just can't make it work for me.

I set up a minimal example to illustrate what I try to do:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{variations}
\begin{document}
\variations
x & -2 & & -1 & & \;1 & & 2 \\
f'(x) & & - & & \ha & & + & \\
f(x) & \h{\sqrt3} & \d & \b0 & \hv & \b0 & \cl & \h{\sqrt3\;} \\
\fin
\end{document}
```

The problem is that some of the commands (not all), which are defined in a file called 'variations.mac' can't be handled when I try to compile with pdflatex (pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.16 (TeX Live 2015/MacPorts 2015_8) (preloaded format=pdflatex)). 
For example `\d`, which should produce an arrow, gives me an undefined control sequence error.

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \,\raise 0\p@int \hbox {\f@nt 
                                     D}\,
```

It's defined as

```
\def\d{\@rrow{0\p@int}{D}}
```

and I assume the problem originates from this part `\@rrow{0\p@int}` (just my guess). I'm no expert, so don't really understand what exactly it refers to. I really hope someone will be able to help me, since I unsuccessfully tried to figure out the issue with a colleague of mine for a couple of days now.

Thank you in advance for your efforts, hints and answers!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. The user guide of the `variations` package (version of 2006/09/13) does not list macros named `\ha`, `\b`, `\cl`, or `\hv`. Is there maybe a similarly-named package out there that provides definitions for such macros which you intend to be using instead of `variations`? TeXLive lists `tableaux`, `tablor`, `tabularew`, and `tabvar` (as well as, of course, `variations`) as packages to aid in the construction of tables of signs and variations.

Comment: @Mico I didn't look at the documentation as I expected it to be in French, but the package does define them in the `.mac` file.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I think you refer to version 0.3, which is also available on ctan, but I'm using version 0.8 from 2010.

Comment: You can use tkz-tab for this kind of table

Comment: Since TeX Live doesn't provide version 0.8 of the package, my guess is that your colleague has properly installed the package in the local tree.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TeX Live (standard, MacTeX or MacPorts) doesn't provide version 0.8 of `variations`, but only version 0.3.

You can install the files in your personal tree or in the local tree.

### Personal tree

Open a Terminal and go to the directory where you unpacked `variations-0.8.tar.gz`. Do `cd variations-0.8` and `ls -l`. You should get something like

```
-rw-r--r--@ 1 staff   1870 Mar 28  2010 ALIRE
-rw-r--r--@ 1 staff  35147 Mar 28  2010 COPYING
-rw-r--r--@ 1 staff   1587 Mar 28  2010 README
-rw-r--r--@ 1 staff  78330 Mar 28  2010 docvariations.pdf
-rw-r--r--@ 1 staff   5673 Mar 28  2010 docvariations.tex
drwxr-xr-x@ 5 staff    170 Mar 28  2010 variations/
-rw-r--r--@ 1 staff   2185 Mar 28  2010 variations.mf
```

Now do the following steps

```
mkdir -p $(kpsewhich -var-value TEXMFHOME)/tex/latex
mkdir -p $(kpsewhich -var-value TEXMFHOME)/doc/latex/variations
mkdir -p $(kpsewhich -var-value TEXMFHOME)/fonts/source/variations
mv variations $(kpsewhich -var-value TEXMFHOME)/tex/latex/
mv ALIRE COPYING README docvariations* $(kpsewhich -var-value TEXMFHOME)/doc/latex/variations
mv variations.mf $(kpsewhich -var-value TEXMFHOME)/fonts/source/variations
```

Now test the installation by compiling the file that previously gave problems.

### Local tree

Do exactly the same steps, but prefixing each command with `sudo` and changing `TEXMFHOME` into `TEXMFLOCAL`. Finally add

```
sudo mktexlsr
```

### Differences

What's the difference between the two installations? With the first method only you (as a user of the machine) have available the package. With the second method, any user has access to it.

Comment: See also my comment to cfr's answer. Having followed these instructions (for "Personal tree"), [here's my result](http://i.imgur.com/fSo88Tv.png). I'd call that successful. :)

Comment: This also worked for me. Extraordinary! Thank you very much for your solution and clear instructions, I would never have come up with something like this myself!

Answer (score 3):

The package provides a font which TeX needs to be able to find in order to use the package, but this font is located in the top-level directory rather than with the `.sty`, `.tex` and `.mac` file. If you drop the `.mf` and other files into your working directory (with your document), then TeX can find the font file and your example compiles fine:

[image: variations]

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for your suggestion, your result is exactly what I'm looking for. Unfortunately it doesn't solve the issue. I have all these files in my directory (.tex, .mac, .sty, .mf) - double-checked again. For my colleague it does compile fine as well. The only difference between us is that he is using linux and I'm using a mac. Can it be related to that?

Comment: It shouldn't be. I am using GNU/Linux, though. If I had to guess, I'd say it was more likely an issue with `macports` than Mac *per se*, but I don't have a Mac available to test. Can you add the complete log to your question after ensuring the files are all in your working directory?

Comment: I have a Mac (10.10.5) with recent install of MacTeX-2015 Distribution. I've tried this: [my TeXstudio file](http://i.imgur.com/4wXvIY8.png), and [the working directory contents](http://i.imgur.com/9MuDISd.png). I also tried following the instructions in the README, and although it all "ran", I probably put them in the wrong place. =/ Hope this helps, somehow!